# I am trying to format namenode in hdfs but says: permission denied

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, permission-denied

I am trying to format namenode . For this I have tried.

```
hduser@Ubuntu:/usr/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.1$ bin/hdfs namenode -format
```

It says:

```
bin/hdfs: line 304: /root/software/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/java: Permission denied
bin/hdfs: line 304: exec: /root/software/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/java: cannot execute: Permission denied
```

Comment: Formatting:  shell commands and output

Comment: [15-second guess] If hdfs isn't running as root, why is it accessing paths in /root? /root is mode 0700 for a reason :)

Comment: so what is the reason and how can I get out of it?? @moshbear

Comment: @Donald_Miner. Can You help Sir, as I am new to hadoop.

Answer (score 1):

So, you have an odd install. It looks like you are trying to reference a JDK installation that is installed to /root (this is very unusual). You are getting permission denied because you are trying to run a command as a non-privileged that depends on that JDK installation that your user can't access.

Running as root would probably make this error go away but you probably have an unorthodox installation that might need to be reconsidered.

Comment: So what could be the solution in this case.